# R: Combine Factors Dynamically

Tags: r

I want to do the following:

1. Open a dataset.
2. Get the factor levels for a dependent variable
3. Loop through the factor levels
4. Create a new temporary column for a new dependent variable factor
5. For each level, change all other level names to "other" and insert in new column
6. Run some analyses (I know what to do here once factor levels recoded).

I don't know how to do point 5 above (and I have spent some time researching)

```
indf <- read.csv(".\\datafiles\\jobDescription\\nouns-categorical_R1.csv")     

majorAsFactor <- levels(as.factor(indf$Major0))     

for(i in majorAsFactor)     
{     
  printToLog(i)     
  Major1 <- vector("character")     
  indf["Major1"] <- Major1     

}
```

Comment: Your points on 4 nd 5 are not clear.  Could you show a small reproducible example and expected output (until 5)

Comment: Thanks, but I just figured it out.

Comment: Spent two hours on this, then figured it out within minutes of posting

Comment: Just make dummy columns, e.g. `library(tidyverse); iris %>% mutate(id = row_number(), i = 1) %>% spread(Species, i, fill = 0)` or in base, maybe `cbind(iris, as.data.frame.matrix(table(seq(nrow(iris)), iris$Species)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer by changing my google search to "recoding factors". Sometimes it's all in finding the right keywords.

The answer is as follows:

```
  indf$Major1[indf$Major0==i] <- as.character(i)
  indf$Major1[indf$Major0!=i] <- "OTHER"
```

Comment: indf$Major1 <- ifelse(indf$Major0 %in% majorAsFactor, as.character(indf$Major0), "OTHER") 
you need not a loop for that, if else suffices